# Apple Sign in Javascript :: How to handle the successful signin callback (redirect_uri)

Tags: javascript, apple-sign-in

I was able to inject apple sign in to the website by initiating the scopes/client id, redirect URI .. etc

now on successful login, apple redirects the response to the redirect URI using a post response, excuse my ignorance! but how can I handle this callback on my website ? is it something I can use in the Apple library itself ? or something I need to build myself?  I was expecting to get the token and pass it to the backend as I am using RESTFul API with the backend

My page is something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
     <style>
        .signin-button {
            width: 210px;
            height: 40px;
        }
    </style>

        <meta name="appleid-signin-client-id" content="com.xxx.web">
        <meta name="appleid-signin-scope" content="name email">
        <meta name="appleid-signin-redirect-uri" content="https://xxx.xxx.com">
        <meta name="appleid-signin-state" content="authorized">
</head>
<body>

    <html>

    <body>

        <div id="appleid-signin" data-color="white" data-border="true" data-type="sign in"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appleid.cdn-apple.com/appleauth/static/jsapi/appleid/1/en_US/appleid.auth.js"></script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

redirect uri is mandatory for apple signin and should be a valid endpoint e.g

which accepts post request, Apple will call the endpoint and pass the **code** and **id_token** upon successful authentication.

Below is an example of a PHP controller

```
public function loginAppleAction(Request $request)
{
    $code = $request->request->get('code');
    $token = $request->request->get('id_token');

    // authorize the user in your system.
   // id_token is a JWT token that contains scope info like the email of the user. you can decode the JWT token using any JWT lib available.
  // make user login into your system.

}
```

The host specified in appleid-signin-redirect-uri must include a domain name. It can’t be an IP address or localhost.

on the successful response from the redirect URI you can also catch the javascript event if you required to do additional tasks.

```
document.addEventListener('AppleIDSignInOnSuccess', function(data) {
         location.reload();    
});
```